# preg_match_all replaces first ocurrence only @user php

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have created this function to chek the mentioned `@users`

```
function user_links($string,$table_users,$pdo) {
    preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/',$string,$matches);
           //
        $sql="
      SELECT id_user,user 
      FROM $table_sers 
      WHERE user= :user LIMIT 1";
        $sql = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
        $sql->bindParam(':user', $match,PDO::PARAM_STR, 20); 

    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {

        $sql->execute();

        $res = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            $id_user=$res['id_user'];
            $user=$res['user'];

            $from = "/@(" . $match . ")(?!\w)/";
            $to = "<a href='user.phhp?id=$id_user'>@".$match."</a>";
            $string = preg_replace($from, $to, $string);
        }

        return $string;
    }
}
```

Im trying to link the mentioned users with the next `string` but it only replaces trhe first ocurrence...

```
@cat,@dog and @turtle is in the db
```

**the main string**

```
 $string="Hi Im @cat and not @cat2, yes you are @dog, @squirrel and @turtle ";

   echo user_links($string,$table_users,$pdo);
```

What it retrieves:

```
//Hi Im <a>@cat</a> and not @cat2, yes you are @dog, @squirrel and @turtle
```

@dog neither, @turtled are replaced...despite they are in the database..

**What am doing wrong?**

Comment: You need to move `return $string` after the `foreach` closing bracket `}`

Comment: ya I have tried. it doesnt owrk neither. thanks

Comment: If you're trying to match only whole words, use `\b` rather than `(?!\w)`

Comment: At the end of each loop (where the return used to be) try `echo $string.PHP_EOL;`

Comment: @Barmar thank you. great insight. Ive edited the post. well any clue abou my question. I still cant find a way to get it.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the query. Isn't `$match` the same as `$user`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `$id_user` in the replacement?

Comment: You might find [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) useful in this case.

Comment: @Sammitch Indeed, I was in the process of writing an answer showing that when I came up with the above questions.

Comment: @Barmar yes I want to add up ``$id_user` to the retrieved mention

Comment: Something like `href="scriptname.php?id=$id_user"`?

Comment: @barman yes. I can make it if use the raw preg_match_all code witin the main code, but if I try to make a function of it, it fails.

Comment: I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create your query dynamically to look up all the IDs, so you don't need to do the string replacements in a loop.

Second, you can use `preg_replace_callback()` to generate the replacement strings dynamically. Put all the mappings from username to ID in an associative array, and use the array in the callback function.

```
<?php
function user_links($string,$table_users,$pdo) {
    preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/',$string,$matches);

    $in_string = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($matches[1]), '?'));
    $sql="
      SELECT id_user,user 
      FROM $table_sers 
      WHERE user in ($in_string)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sql->execute($matches[1]);

    $mapping = [];
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $mapping[$row['user']] = $row['id_user'];
    }

    $string = preg_replace_callback('/@(\w+)/', function($matches) use($mapping) {
            if (isset($mapping[$matches[1]])) {
                return "<a href='scriptname.php?id={$mapping[$matches[1]]}'>{$matches[0]}</a>";
            } else {
                return $matches[0];
            }
        }, $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: awesome ansewr. I think it works....I have a little detail. Im using a very old php server `4.0.3` this `preg_replace_callback()` retrieves error `syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in `. I know I need to upgrade, but meanwhile I use this server version, is there any possibility to find a suitable solution for this type of php version? thank you.

Comment: With an old version you need to use the `create_function()` function. You can see an example in the `preg_replace_callback()` documentation.

Comment: it will also have to have `global $mapping` in it, since `use()` didn't exist then.

Comment: I have globals disabled in my online server.

Comment: Are you talking about `register_globals`? That's not related to the `global` declaration inside functions.